# What is the Http Status Error code return for user trying failure data from Db?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, httpwebresponse

I have using oracle db. New data inserted in oracle using Java API and try to get the response from read end point using java API call. in DB one field name `TRAN_OUTCOME="Success"` will get the response. If `TRAN_OUTCOME="Failure"` will not get the response. failure case have throwing Exception. what was the Http Status error code want to return this scenario?

Throwing message format:

```
[
  {
    "Message": "Process associated with the Process ID has ended in failure. Kindly re-initiate the process.";
  }
]
```

Comment: maybe [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) on Wikipedia (or similar pages on the internet)

Answer (score 1):

In case of Http Status codes, the general practice is

- 4XX: In case the processing failed as a result of some validation/condition is not satisfied by the client (calling service)
- 5XX: when some error occurred on server side

If there is any database exception which is not due to parameters sent by Client then you can return 500. If the data sent by client is causing some database constraint violation like Unique constraint etc. then you can return appropriate 4XX status code

There is also unconventional way where people send 2XX response but in the response data, they mention ERROR:TRUE etc. to indicate failure. But this way is not recommended.